# Use Location.bearingTo(<Location>) method

Tags: android, location

I want to calculate the bearing from my current location to a fixed custom position in android, but the parameter required under bearingTo is Location type, not LatLng, how can i put a custom location to Location type?

```
float bearing = mLocationClient.getLastLocation().bearingTo(<Location>);
```

Comment: have you even read the documentation for `Location`?

Comment: @Simon Location test = new Location(<String>);test.setLatitude(<double>);test.setLongitude(<double>); problem is initialise, as the documentation said, string is services provider name or networks name, but here what should i put to initialise it?

Comment: Like I said, have you read the documentation?  From the documentation - `Location(String provider)`

Answer (score 0):

```
android.location.Location waypoint;
```

...

```
waypoint = new android.location.Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
waypoint.setLatitude(52.230017);
waypoint.setLongitude(21.010977);
```

...

```
public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location)
{
 float angle_waypoint = location.bearingTo(waypoint);
}
```